# Проблема с отображением иконок Font Awesome

Tags: css3, html5, fontawesome

Подключаю два файла стилей к документу:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/svg/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" />`

И у меня не работает второй, хотя путь указан правильно.
Вот файловая структура:

```
-app
--css
---main.min.css
--libs
---svg
----fontavesome-all.min.css
```

Теперь, вся непонятность заключается в том, что, когда я подключаю оба файла сразу, то не работает, но КОГДА я подключаю только второй файл, то все работает. Получается, что Font Awesome работает только без main.min.css. В чем проблема?[image: Фото, когда подключены два файла стилей сразу]

[image: Фото, где главный первый стиль отключен]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключи сначала fontawesome а потом свои стили(по твоей инфе это маусимум что я могу сказать). А проблема скорее в том что main.css конфликтит со стилями авесома, посмотри через инспектор стили иконки.

Comment: Вы были правы, я допустил ошибку в базовых стилях основного файла, случайно добавив ко всем псевдоэлементам шрифт: Roboto. Это была моя ошибка, иконки подхватили базовый шрифт и случился конфликт между стилями)